# How to specify openflashchart link (the on-click handler actually)

Tags: flash, charts, hyperlink, onclick, openflashchart2

I've got a bar chart with some elements.values as this:

```
  "elements":[
      {"values":
         [
           {"right":12,
            "colour":"#a55feb",
            "on-click":"http://myurl.com/"
           },
           {"right":25,
            "colour":"#5757ff",
            "on-click":"http://another.one/"
           }
         ]
       }]
```

This doesn't work, although the openflashchart doc says

> Each dot can have its own on click
>   event.

and

> Don't forget that all charts can have on click events

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually, http://forums.openflashchart.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1924 says that it does not work with hbar char type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the patched version of open flash chart from http://www.ofc2dz.com/ does the trick (plus you can set the window target).